# Recommended way to make /srv/ftp writable?

Tags: permissions, ftp

I have installed vsftp, and because I'm on Debian it automatically created the user ftp. I have set nopriv_user=ftp. Apart from that I haven't made any changes.

This ftp server is only going to allow anonymous logins, but I want several users on the Debian box to be able to move files into /srv/ftp.

/srv/ftp is owned by user root, and group ftp. So I figure the best solution would be to add every user who is to have write access to the ftp group.

Is this the normal/correct way of doing this?

Comment: "Is this the normal/correct way of doing this?" i would say it is a right way

Comment: Just out of interest, what are the other ways it can be done? The only other way I can think of is to set /srv/ftp to be world writable...

Comment: So i've missed something in your query...i was thinking that beeing a member of ftp group was working...if not, please improve your question and describe more precisely your problem. what is the output of "ls -ld /srv/ftp" ?

Comment: Just tried it, and it's not working, the output is: drwxr-xr-x 2 root ftp 4096 Dec 11 00:51 /srv/ftp

Comment: Hang on I just realized I have to set the group permissions to write

Comment: Okay have added write permission for the group, but still not working: drwxrwxr-x 2 root ftp 4096 Dec 11 00:51 ftp

Comment: Try 777 for a few minutes, just to try...

Comment: Yes, just set a+w and it works. Some more info: if I run "groups" the group ftp does not appear in the output. If I run "groups user" then the ftp group does appear. Does that mean the group doesn't exist and I have to create it?

Comment: Maybe, send the output for "cat /etc/group"

Comment: Here is output of cat /etc/group | grep ftp: ftp:x:123:user
I can post the rest if necessary...

Comment: You mean "a+w" or "o+w" ? now send "cat /etc/passwd | grep ftp"

Comment: Okay, just discovered I can write to files but not create them... any ideas why that would be? [stand by for passwd output]

Comment: ftp:x:114:123:ftp daemon,,,:/srv/ftp:/bin/false

Comment: I just set a+w to test, I have since put it back to: drwxrwxr-x

Comment: Googled for being able to write to files but not create them, and I am going to try logging out and back in. Will report back...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh supplementary group memberships without logging in again?](https://serverfault.com/questions/74934/refresh-supplementary-group-memberships-without-logging-in-again)

Answer (score 0):

Logging out and back in fixed it.  I guess you need to do that for the group membership to fully take effect.